# Retrieving all Cookies in Python

Tags: python, cookies

How do I read back all of the cookies in Python without knowing their names?

Comment: When you say "read them back", do you mean a) read them from an HTTP response, or b) read them out of the CookieJar? Or is there a (c) interpretation?

Comment: There is a (c) as well :) c_1) Someone might ask about the cookies of HIS python session... E.g. if the python script is a .cgi ( for that see e.g. os.environ['HTTP_COOKIE'] answer by Matt Lacey, depending on the web server used to serve the cgi)  c_2) Same question if its a notebook running in jupyter (web server is tornado)

Answer (score 24):

Not sure if this is what you are looking for, but here is a simple example where you put cookies in a cookiejar and read them back:

```
from urllib2 import Request, build_opener, HTTPCookieProcessor, HTTPHandler
import cookielib

#Create a CookieJar object to hold the cookies
cj = cookielib.CookieJar()
#Create an opener to open pages using the http protocol and to process cookies.
opener = build_opener(HTTPCookieProcessor(cj), HTTPHandler())

#create a request object to be used to get the page.
req = Request("http://www.about.com")
f = opener.open(req)

#see the first few lines of the page
html = f.read()
print html[:50]

#Check out the cookies
print "the cookies are: "
for cookie in cj:
    print cookie
```

Comment: If the cookie I got is `<Cookie _b="AQYJuqIEi9xHvY1vHG9i6bkSgQNv8b0/04YaLTPf4J0t4fOpb33Gr63a3y+nC6H2I0Y=" for .google.com/>`, how do I get `_b` part? `cookie["_b"]` does not work

Answer (score 6):

Put `os.environ['HTTP_COOKIE']` into an array:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import os

 if 'HTTP_COOKIE' in os.environ:
  cookies = os.environ['HTTP_COOKIE']
  cookies = cookies.split('; ')
  handler = {}

  for cookie in cookies:
   cookie = cookie.split('=')
   handler[cookie[0]] = cookie[1]
```

Comment: That would be great, and exactly what I need, except there is no HTTP_COOKIE... I am using jupyter... (which would mean Tornado) where does it stores the cookies?

Answer (score 5):

This may be exactly what you are looking for.

Python 3.4

```
import requests

r = requests.get('http://www.about.com/')
c = r.cookies
i = c.items()

for name, value in i:
    print(name, value)
```

Answer (score 4):

Look at the `Cookie:` headers in the HTTP response you get, parse their contents with module `Cookie` in the standard library.

Comment: How do you look at the cookies in the HTTP response? That depends on how you are getting that response, for example urllib.urlretrieve returns a tuple of 2 items, the second one is the httplib.HTTPMessage with the metadata; if you prefer urllib.urlopen, you get the HTTPMessage by calling .info() on the pseudo-file object that urlopen returns; etc, etc.