# how can i read cookies with python

Tags: python, cookies

i tried looking that up with google, i found no examples, i tried with stack overflow i found topics were helpful but at the end it didnt gave me the desired result.
what am trying to do is create a cookie from a php script "http://127.0.0.1/web/accounts/login.php" it saves a cookie with [user]=>dwaik, i tried reading that cookie from another php script "http://127.0.0.1/web/accounts/read_cookie.php" and it successfully reads it! the problem is i couldnt read it with python using the code

```
from urllib2 import Request, build_opener, HTTPCookieProcessor, HTTPHandler
import cookielib
cj = cookielib.CookieJar()
opener = build_opener(HTTPCookieProcessor(cj), HTTPHandler())
req = Request("http://127.0.0.1/web/accounts/login.php")
f = opener.open(req)
print "the cookies are: "
for cookie in cj:
    print cookie
```

this snippet was taken from [Retrieving all Cookies in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/921532/retrieving-cookies-python)
it doesnt read my cookie, however i launched the login.php form google chrome and from IE, help would be appreciated

Comment: possible duplicate of [Retrieving all Cookies in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/921532/retrieving-all-cookies-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use mechanize.

```
import cookielib
import urllib2
import mechanize

br = mechanize.Browser()
cookiejar = cookielib.LWPCookieJar()
br.set_cookiejar( cookiejar )
br.set_proxies({"http": "yourProxyHereIfneeded","https": 
"yourProxyHereIfneeded"})
br.set_handle_equiv( True )
br.set_handle_gzip( True )
br.set_handle_redirect( True ) 
br.set_handle_referer( True )
br.set_handle_robots( False )

br.set_handle_refresh( mechanize._http.HTTPRefreshProcessor(), 
max_time = 1)

br.addheaders = [ ( 'User-agent', 'yourHeadervalueifNeeded' ) ]

#this one will open you what your desired domain
response = br.open("theDomain")

#and this one stands for saving the cookies for you.
cookiejar.save('cookies.txt', ignore_discard=True, 
ignore_expires=True)

#after you saved your cookie a txt or dump with pickle for example. 
#You can easly load it while configure the browser Object at the start 
#our example code.

br = mechanize.Browser()
cookiejar = cookielib.LWPCookieJar()
cookiejar.load('cookie_login.txt', ignore_discard=True, 
ignore_expires=True)
br.set_cookiejar( cookiejar )
```

For more informaiton i suggest you to visit http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/doc.html#dealing-with-bad-html

And a good prepared cheetsheet for mechanize for you can visit.
http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/cheatsheet/python-mechanize-cheat-sheet

I hope this one helps out.