# Python request module - Getting response cookies

Tags: cookies, python-3.x, module, request, response

I am using python 3.3 and the request module. And I am trying understand how to retrieve cookies from a response. The request documentation says:

```
url = 'http://example.com/some/cookie/setting/url'
r = requests.get(url)

r.cookies['example_cookie_name']
```

That doesn't make sense, how do you get data from a cookie if you don't already know the name of the cookie? Maybe I don't understand how cookies work? If I try and print the response cookies I get:

```
<<class 'requests.cookies.RequestsCookieJar'>[]>
```

Thanks

Comment: How to retrieve all cookies in Python: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/921532/retrieving-cookies-python

Answer (score 20):

You can retrieve them iteratively:

```
import requests

r = requests.get('http://example.com/some/cookie/setting/url')

for c in r.cookies:
    print(c.name, c.value)
```

Answer (score 3):

Cookies are stored in headers as well. If this isn't working for you, check your headers for:

```
"Set-Cookie: Name=Value; [Expires=Date; Max-Age=Value; Path=Value]"
```

Answer (score 2):

I got the following code from [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/921532/retrieving-all-cookies-in-python):

```
from urllib2 import Request, build_opener, HTTPCookieProcessor, HTTPHandler
import cookielib

#Create a CookieJar object to hold the cookies
cj = cookielib.CookieJar()
#Create an opener to open pages using the http protocol and to process cookies.
opener = build_opener(HTTPCookieProcessor(cj), HTTPHandler())

#create a request object to be used to get the page.
req = Request("http://www.about.com")
f = opener.open(req)

#see the first few lines of the page
html = f.read()
print html[:50]

#Check out the cookies
print "the cookies are: "
for cookie in cj:
    print cookie
```

See if this works for you.

Answer (score 1):

You can now get a `dict` of all the response cookies with:

```py
response.cookies.get_dict()
```