# not getting all cookie info using python requests module

Tags: python, cookies, python-requests

I'm learning how to login to an example website using python requests module. This
[Video Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eRSJSKG4mDA)
got me started. From all the cookies that I see in GoogleChrome>Inspect Element>NetworkTab, I'm not able to retrieve all of them using the following code:

```
import requests
with requests.Session() as s:
    url = 'http://www.noobmovies.com/accounts/login/?next=/'
    s.get(url)
    allcookies = s.cookies.get_dict()
    print allcookies
```

Using this I only get csrftoken like below:

```
{'csrftoken': 'ePE8zGxV4yHJ5j1NoGbXnhLK1FQ4jwqO'}
```

But in google chrome, I see all these other cookies apart from csrftoken (sessionid, _gat, _ga etc):
[image: Google Chrome ScreenShot]

I even tried the following code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20898394/how-to-read-cookie-in-python), but the result was the same:

```
from urllib2 import Request, build_opener, HTTPCookieProcessor, HTTPHandler
import cookielib

#Create a CookieJar object to hold the cookies
cj = cookielib.CookieJar()
#Create an opener to open pages using the http protocol and to process cookies.
opener = build_opener(HTTPCookieProcessor(cj), HTTPHandler())

#create a request object to be used to get the page.
req = Request("http://www.noobmovies.com/accounts/login/?next=/")
f = opener.open(req)

#see the first few lines of the page
html = f.read()
print html[:50]

#Check out the cookies
print "the cookies are: "
for cookie in cj:
    print cookie
```

Output:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org
the cookies are: 
<Cookie csrftoken=ePE8zGxV4yHJ5j1NoGbXnhLK1FQ4jwqO for www.noobmovies.com/>
```

So, how can I get all the cookies ? Thanks.

Comment: are any of those request cookies added by google? how could you get the  cookies sent with the request from the response?

Comment: @dm03514, I'm not sure. I inspected the same in a safari browser (which supports yahoo search) and got back the same list of cookies. Can you elaborate on the second part that you stated ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The cookies being set are from other pages/resources, probably loaded by JavaScript code. You can check it making the request to the page only (without running the JS code), using tools such as [wget](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/), [curl](https://curl.haxx.se/) or [httpie](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/httpie).

The only cookie this server set is `csrftoken`, as you can see in:

```
$ wget --server-response 'http://www.noobmovies.com/accounts/login/?next=/'
--2016-02-01 22:51:55--  http://www.noobmovies.com/accounts/login/?next=/
Resolving www.noobmovies.com (www.noobmovies.com)... 69.164.217.90
Connecting to www.noobmovies.com (www.noobmovies.com)|69.164.217.90|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 
  HTTP/1.1 200 OK
  Server: nginx/1.4.6 (Ubuntu)
  Date: Tue, 02 Feb 2016 00:51:58 GMT
  Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
  Transfer-Encoding: chunked
  Connection: keep-alive
  Vary: Accept-Encoding
  Expires: Tue, 02 Feb 2016 00:51:58 GMT
  Vary: Cookie,Accept-Encoding
  Cache-Control: max-age=0
  Set-Cookie: csrftoken=XJ07sWhMpT1hqv4K96lXkyDWAYIFt1W5; expires=Tue, 31-Jan-2017 00:51:58 GMT; Max-Age=31449600; Path=/
  Last-Modified: Tue, 02 Feb 2016 00:51:58 GMT
Length: unspecified [text/html]
Saving to: ‘index.html?next=%2F’

index.html?next=%2F             [      <=>                                   ]  10,83K  2,93KB/s    in 3,7s    

2016-02-01 22:52:03 (2,93 KB/s) - ‘index.html?next=%2F’ saved [11085]
```

Note the `Set-Cookie` line.