# How to see all cookies being set when a GET request is made

Tags: python-3.x, cookies, python-requests

Referencing [not getting all cookie info using python requests module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29928591/not-getting-all-cookie-info-using-python-requests-module)

The OP saw many cookies being set on Chrome, but does not see most of those cookies in his Python Requests code. The reason given was that "The cookies being set are from other pages/resources, probably loaded by JavaScript code."

This is the function I'm using to try and get cookies that are loaded when a URL is accessed:

```
from requests import get
from requests.exceptions import RequestException
from contextlib import closing

def get_cookies(url):
    """
    Returns the cookies from the response of `url` when making a HTTP GET request.
    """
    try:
        s = Session()
        with closing(get(url, stream=True)) as resp:
            return resp.cookies

    except RequestException as e:
        print('Error during requests to {0} : {1}'.format(url, str(e)))
        return None
```

But using this function, I only see cookies set by the URL, and not others like advertisement cookies. Given this setup, how do I view the other cookies, exactly as how Chrome sees them? I.e. how do I see all cookies being set when a GET request is made, including those from other pages/resources?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Took a bit of work, but I managed to get it working.
Basically needed selenium and chrome to actually load the website and all 3rd party stuff. One of the outputs is a sqlite3 database of cookies in `./chrome_dir/Default/Cookies` which you can just fetch for your own use.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import sqlite3

def get_cookies(url):
    """
    Returns the cookies from the response of `url` when making a HTTP GET request.
    """
    co = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    co.add_argument("--user-data-dir=chrome_dir")    # creates a directory to store all the chrome data
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=co)
    driver.get(url)
    driver.quit()

    conn = sqlite3.connect(r'./chrome_stuff/Default/Cookies')
    c = conn.cursor()
    c.execute("SELECT * FROM 'cookies'")

    return c.fetchall()
```