# Scraping data from external site with username and password

Tags: python, authentication, cookies

I have an application with many users, some of these users have an account on an external website with data I want to scrape.

This external site has a members area protected with a email/password form. This sets some cookies when submitted (a couple of ASP ones). You can then pull up the needed page and grab the data the external site holds for the user that just logged in.

The external site has no API.

I envisage my application asking users for their credentials to the external site, logging in on their behalf and grabbing the data we want.

How would I go about this in Python, i.e. do I need to run a GUI web browser on the server that Python prods to handle the cookies (I'd rather not)?

Answer (score 2):

1. Find the call the page makes to the backend by inspecting what is the format of the login call in your browser's inspector.
2. Make the same request after using either [`getpass`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/getpass.html) to get user credentials from the terminal or via a GUI. You can use [`urllib2`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html) to make the requests.
3. Save all the cookies from the response in a [cookiejar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/921744/987185).
4. Reuse the cookies in subsequent requests and fetch data.

Then, profit.

Comment: Your `cookiejar` link is the same as the `getpass` link

Comment: @heinst Fixed the link. Thanks for the heads up. :)

Answer (score 1):

Usually, this is performed with session.

I'm recommending you to use requests library (http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) in order to do that.

You can use the Session feature (http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/#session-objects). Simply perform an authentication HTTP request (url and parameters depends of the website you want to request), and then, perform a request towards the ressource you want to scrape.

Without further information, we cannot help you more.