# How can I fetch info from the "Request Headers" of a specific request from the network tab using Python?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, python-requests

I'm trying to fetch a ***specific*** value of a ***specific*** request from the network tab using python.

For example, let's say I want to fetch the value stored in ***cookie*** from one of the ***get*** requests:

When I open the **network tab** I get these Fetch/XHR requests, I select the ***get*** request:
[Image explanation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aeFxf.jpg)

After I click on the ***get*** request and I scroll down to the "*Request Headers*" list I get the following values, I want to fetch the value of "***cookie***": [Image explanation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t9Hbz.jpg)

How can I get this specific value using python and print it in the console?
Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you trying to watch the network traffic and listen for e specific connection or do you just want to know the current content of said cookie?

Comment: I'm trying to fetch the current content of said cookie, from my computer and my browser, automatically using python @white

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/921532/retrieving-all-cookies-in-python

Comment: @white unfortunately, it doesn't. The cookie I need to retrieve contains an auth token to use the websites API, this auth token is granted to the cookie only if I'm logged in to the site... that's why I thought it was better to use selenium to do it

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using seleniumwire:

```
from seleniumwire import webdriver  # Import from seleniumwire

# Create a new instance of the chrome web driver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
url = "https://www.google.com/"  
driver.get(url)

# Access requests via the `requests` attribute
for request in driver.requests:
    if request.response:
    # here you need to filter the name of the url request you want
    # if "name_of_the_url_in_header" in request.url
        print(
            request.url
            request.headers['cookie']
        )
```